# Different between actions

Tags: php, forms

I want to know different between `<form action="#" method="post">` and `<form action="name of file" method="post">`

I am always using # but don't know disadvantages.

Can you explain why I should use # or file name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form action = file name
```

It is used to send a request on the other page(i.e your file name) containing your form fields(inputs) with methods like GET and POST.

example my HTML page is having a form then and my PHP page is having all the backend code. Whatever I need to do with form inputs. I will give the file name of my PHP page in action. the action attribute of the form is used to send the form request to the destination we want to with methods like the POST and GET. If you do not want to send a request to another Page and want it to your default page. You can leave `action =''` attribute of the form empty as I did.

An action of # indicates that the form stays on the same page, simply suffixing the URL with a #. A similar use occurs in anchors. Link for example, will stay on the same page.

Thus, the form is submitted to the same page, which then processes the data etc

Comment: And what about action="#"?

Comment: @Jacob `#` is treated a the same way as in anchor links, i.e, somewhere on the existing page

Answer (score 0):

The content of `action` allows you to know where you will put the code that will process the request.

If you put the name of a file it, then his file will process the request.

For example: you have your form on the `index.php` page and you want to put the PHP code of the form in a `process.php` file. You will put `process.php` in action (`action="process.php"`).

If you do not put anything it is like sending the content of the request to the same file (`index.php`).